# How to capture downloads from Browsers

Tags: java, urlconnection, download-manager

My Name is Rohit Kumawat

I am creating a Download Manager in Java Language. I have almost created it with support for FTP,HTTP & HTTPS(Using JSSE 3.0). Now i want to capture downloads from Browser as IDM or other Downlaod Manager does.

How can i solve this problem ?

How can i register my Download Manager with different Browsers?

Thanks in Advance...